# Can't debug php with VS Code

Tags: php, json, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug my php with wamp, xdebug and [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug) extension, but I can't get it to work. This is the end of my php.ini (C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.4\php.ini):

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension ="C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.4/ext/php_xdebug-2.4.1-7.0-vc14-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp"
```

My launch.json (C:\wamp64\www\CubePicker.vscode\launch.json):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

Settings.json:

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
    "emmet.syntaxProfiles": 
    {
        "php": "html"
    },

    "php.validate.executablePath": "C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.4/php.exe",

}
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? I launch the debugger in VS Code, then run the webpage through my browser, which I assume is correct...? How can I fix this and make it hit the breakpoints I put in?

Let me know if you need anything else.

Thanks!

[EDIT]: I have been into phpinfo(), found the path of the loaded php.ini, and edited it to add the first chunk of code. This didn't fix the problem.

[EDIT]: I have also copied the whole of my phpinfo() here: http://pastebin.com/4Jk5TuQj

Comment: If you are running a php.exe then add the XDEBUG params to the `\wamp\bin\php\php7.0.4\php.ini` as well. That ini file controls the PHP CLI and does not have XDEBUG configured by default

Comment: Is that different to \wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.4\php.ini? If so, where is it located?

Comment: The file you need to edit is listed in `phpinfo()` and restart the service after editing.

Comment: I've just edited that file and added the same bit of config to it, but it still doesn't hit the breakpoint...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Author of the extension here.
As stated in the readme, you need to add

```
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

to your php.ini so XDebug will actually make a request to VS Code.

I also searched your phpinfo()  output but there was no XDebug section.
You should use the XDebug config wizard here: xdebug.org/wizard.php

Comment: I've added the line stated to my php.ini, but still no change. I can browse to the file with something like my browser, and it can see that the path exists. Is it definitely double quotes that you have to surround the path in?

Comment: You should use the XDebug config wizard here: https://xdebug.org/wizard.php

Comment: Thanks so much, that's really helped me out :D

Comment: I didn't think I could do that, as it is a comment not an answer.

Comment: I added it to the answer :)

Comment: There you go :D

Comment: zend_extension="/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1

(I found I needed all three of these remote parameters, just for the next guy).